# How ~12 gives -13 in decimal?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

I have a question in my programming class, it is: What is the value of ~12 and the answer is -13. I don't understand why? I convert 13 base 10 to binary, which is 1100, than I switched all the 1 for 0 and vice versa, it gives me 0011, so I thought the answer was 3 but it's not.

Comment: So what is 13 expressed in binary again?

Comment: What operation is `~`?

Comment: There are an infinite number of 0 bits on the left side.

Comment: You can see a practical use of this in my answer to a mostly-unrelated question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63552117/1405588

Comment: @esqew Are you asking for the name, or what do you mean?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I’m simply trying to understand what mathematical operation is denoted using the tilde `~` as I’m personally unfamiliar with the symbol being used in this way and a cursory search turned up no relevant results.

Comment: @esqew Just look up all the operators in python.

Comment: Your question says that you *"switched all the 1 for 0 and vice versa"*, so it appears you do indeed understand exactly what `~` does, the issue is that you didn't realise there are infinitely many `0` bits to the left of `1100` which also have to be switched to `1`. Please see the questions I linked to for an explanation of this.

Comment: Negative integers are represented using two's complement in binary.  That's why inverting the bits gives that absolute value plus 1.  For more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Answer (score 3):

Converting `12` to a signed binary number yields `01100` then assuming that `~` is supposed to invert every bit we get `10011` which can be converted from signed binary to decimal yielding `-13`.

Comment: How do you know that when you convert it, it has to be on 5 bits?

Comment: To know whether a signed binary number is positive or not you look at the first digit. If it's 0 it's positive and if it's 1 it's negative. Because we know that the original number is +12 we have to start the number with at least one zero in the binary representation. I suggest that you read more about signed binary numbers.