# Count trailing zeros in R

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

How do I count trailing zeros in a vector of string. For example, if my vector of string is:

```
x = c('0000','1200','1301','X230','9900')
```

The answer should be

```
> numZeros
[1] 4 2 0 1 2
```

I do not want to use multiple `ifelse` as I think a more elegant and faster solution should be present. I tried using modulus, like this

```
y = as.integer(x)
numZeros = (!(y%%10000))+(!(y%%1000))+(!(y%%100))+(!(y%%10))
```

but that would require two conditions to be true.

- Maximum length of the string is fixed (which is true in my case) and
- All the strings in the vector are convertible to integers, which is not true in my case.

Then used `stringr` package and created a solution but it is very lengthy.

```
library(stringr)
numZeros = 
4*str_detect(x,"0000") + 
3*str_detect(x,"[1-9 A-Z]000") + 
2*str_detect(x,"[1-9 A-Z]{2}00") + 
str_detect(x,"[1-9 A-Z]{3}0")
```

Also, I can't figure out whether `str_detect` uses `ifelse` by looking at definition of `str_detect`.

I found same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593355/in-python-how-do-i-count-the-trailing-zeros-in-a-string-or-integer) but for python. If this has been answered for R, please provide the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may match all trailing `0`s and then count them. Here is a base R solution:

```
> matches <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("0(?=0*$)", x, perl=TRUE))
> sapply(matches, length)
[1] 4 2 0 1 2
```

Here, `0(?=0*$)` matches any `0` that is only followed with zero or more (`*`) zeros at the end of the string (`$`).

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gzKfPf/1) and an [R demo online](http://rextester.com/UMU59517).

Comment: Thanks for explaining the solution as well.

Answer (score 6):

I found a simple solution with base `R`:

```
x <- c('0000','1200','1301','X230','9900')
nchar(x) - nchar(sub("0*$", "", x))
# > nchar(x) - nchar(sub("0*$", "", x))
# [1] 4 2 0 1 2
```

Comment: Nice, actually the final output I need is `nchar(sub("0*$", "", x))` only. Awesome. But alas, I can accept only 1 answer.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `str_extract` to extract one or more 0's at the end (`$`) of the string and use `nchar` to get the count.  If needed, assign the `NA` elements to 0

```
library(stringr)
res <- nchar(str_extract(x, "0+$"))
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
res
#[1] 4 2 0 1 2
```

#### data

```
x = c('0000','1200','1301','X230','9900')
```